# container proportions swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, containers

I need clarification on how the container view in Swift 4 is supposed to work.  I was under the impression (maybe falsely so), that if I set up all my labels, buttons, etc. inside of a container, set that container to zero for the left and upper constraints, centered it vertically and horizontally in the main view, and then pinned all of the fields within that container, then everything would be proportionally increased or decreased, depending on the screen size.

I designed my screens on a storyboard, using an iPhone 6 sized screen.
The App should be viewed only in Portrait mode, so I needn't worry about dealing with Landscape modes.  I am finding out that the text fields within the container are keeping their sized fonts; when going to a larger screen (8 Plus), I am getting a large border on the bottom and right.
When going to a smaller screen (SE), most of the verbiage gets truncated.  Have I misunderstood how this is supposed to work, or am I not doing it correctly?

I am almost ready to submit my first App to the Apple Store, but want to make sure that it will handle all possible sized screens.  The 2 IOS courses I've been referring to are pretty vague on exactly how auto layout works.  Also, I am getting over 24 warning messages that all of my fixed width constraints may cause clipping. (15 yard penalty?).

Hopefully, someone out there will have the patience to explain what I thought should be an easy thing to do.  Here are screenshots of my initial view controller using each of the 3 sizes:

[Originally Designed Screen, set to iPhone 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKVRD.png)

[Screen set to iPhone 8 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogXLF.png)

[Screen set to iPhone SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcrz6.png)

Many thanks in advance for helping us out,
Jones

Comment: It's a false impression but are you talking about `UIContainerView` or `UIView` by the way the best for you might be `UIStackView`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I had set these containers up as UIViews.  Does UIStackView work better than what I selected?  If so, what steps would I have to do to accomplish this?  (Haven't even seen UIStackView in my courses.)

Answer (score 0):

Stack views are meant to do exactly what you are trying to do. Here is a version of your app that uses stack views to create the example below. There is also a link to the GitHub page with the code - feel free to use it, tear it apart, whatever. Good luck!

[image]

https://github.com/squarehippo/Baseball2.git